React Query migrating from v3 to v4
I am trying to upgrade react query from v3 to v4. While doing so I am getting some problem. Following same code in v3 and v4 gives different output
const result = useQuery(["user-settings-key"], async () => {
    const userSettings = await userSettingService.getUserSetting({"settingId": 120 });
    return userSettings;
});
console.log(result); 

console.log Output in v3 is as follows. This console.log is printed once
console.log
    {
      status: [Getter],
      fetchStatus: [Getter],
      isLoading: [Getter],
      isSuccess: [Getter],
      isError: [Getter],
      isInitialLoading: [Getter],
      data: [Getter],
      dataUpdatedAt: [Getter],
      error: [Getter],
      errorUpdatedAt: [Getter],
      failureCount: [Getter],
      failureReason: [Getter],
      errorUpdateCount: [Getter],
      isFetched: [Getter],
      isFetchedAfterMount: [Getter],
      isFetching: [Getter],
      isRefetching: [Getter],
      isLoadingError: [Getter],
      isPaused: [Getter],
      isPlaceholderData: [Getter],
      isPreviousData: [Getter],
      isRefetchError: [Getter],
      isStale: [Getter],
      refetch: [Getter],
      remove: [Getter]
    }

console.log Output in v4 is as follows. This console.log is printed few times as status is changed
console.log
    {
      status: 'loading',
      isLoading: true,
      isSuccess: false,
      isError: false,
      isIdle: false,
      data: undefined,
      dataUpdatedAt: 0,
      error: null,
      errorUpdatedAt: 0,
      failureCount: 0,
      errorUpdateCount: 0,
      isFetched: false,
      isFetchedAfterMount: false,
      isFetching: true,
      isRefetching: false,
      isLoadingError: false,
      isPlaceholderData: false,
      isPreviousData: false,
      isRefetchError: false,
      isStale: true,
      refetch: [Function: bound refetch],
      remove: [Function: bound remove]
    }

2nd time
console.log
    {
      status: 'success',
      isLoading: false,
      isSuccess: true,
      isError: false,
      isIdle: false,
      data: { some_vale: null },
      dataUpdatedAt: 047138960,
      error: null,
      errorUpdatedAt: 0,
      failureCount: 0,
      errorUpdateCount: 0,
      isFetched: true,
      isFetchedAfterMount: true,
      isFetching: false,
      isRefetching: false,
      isLoadingError: false,
      isPlaceholderData: false,
      isPreviousData: false,
      isRefetchError: false,
      isStale: true,
      refetch: [Function: bound refetch],
      remove: [Function: bound remove]
    }

and it also prints in 5 times totally with success set to true.
What is happening is v4? I am new to react query so I am not able to figure it out.

since v4, the tracked queries feature is on per default, where we create a shallow object with defineProperty and custom getters to track which properties are used so that we can only re-render the component when one of those has changed. You can read more about it here:
https://tanstack.com/query/latest/docs/framework/react/guides/render-optimizations#tracked-properties
I think in the console, you can click on [Getter] to actually invoke it and see the result. Otherwise, you can trigger all getters with object spread:
console.log({ ...result })

